Log-based alert for Cloud Functions triggered, but no log found
I have a log-based metric and an alert that is configured to trigger on Cloud Function error logs. This is the filter for our metric:
resource.type="cloud_function" and severity >= ERROR

Our team uses GitHub Action to deploy the function via gcloud functions deploy command, and we have noticed that every time we deploy the function for the first time to our production environment, the alert is triggered.
However, when I go to Logs Explorer, I don't see any logs for the same filter. Moreover, it seems that this issue happens only in this specific environment/Google cloud project, and when I deploy to any other environment (e.g. staging) the metric stays at 0.
What could be causing this log-based metric to count 1 when there are no logs for that filter?

Verify if there are any exclusion filters configured in google cloud logging that could be filtering out logs from cloud functions. Also If your function is timing out, it might not log errors correctly before termination, increase the function's timeout duration to address this issue.
